# can't run py files from atom after uninstalling old python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I had been able to run python files via Atom's Open in Browser, but now that I have uninstalled python 2.7 (still have the latest version installed) it throws an error saying I have no program associated with that file type. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A few questions which may help. Are you using the script package ? Have you tried re-installing the Open in Browser package ? Do you run atom from the command line ? When you try to run your python file, do you call python or python3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have script installed but it doesn't seem to work properly so I don't use it. I just tried re-installing Open in Browser, but the the issue persists. I don't run atom from the command line; I just open it like a normal program and load in project folders.

I reinstalled python on my home comp and that solved the issue, but the problem persists on my work laptop after trying all of the provided solutions.

Comment: I run my scripts with script. There are two things I do. First, in the settings of script, I specify that the folder from which the script command needs to be called is the one of the current file. And second, I specify in the launching options (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + O) that the command to execute is python3. This works for me. Another question which may help: what command do you call in the terminal to use python? Because if it is python3 and that atom expects python, then that is maybe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Update your system's path variables because python path is pointing to the previous version which you have uninstalled.

Comment: It looks like it is already set to Python36-32. I uninstalled 2.7